One mesh multiple UV Baking
So i've managed to join the mesh into a single object before rigging. Before doing so i follow this tutorial so that i the textures can be retained even so when it has distinct uv maps {https://youtu.be/Ohg98v0H534?si=NStUAX6htyYhFL7U} i followed this. On this tuts the tutor also showed the overlapping uv island if we edit select all the faces.
Now i want to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNAQgQGRmgQ&t=9s&ab_channel=PixelicaCG but i can't seem to resolve how to do that with one mesh that has multiple uvmaps with the same name.
When i tried to pack uv island manually just like the video said on the bake uv maps, the texture moved on my model.
I don't really know the intricacies behind uvmap tab in blender, how do i bake all of the texture into a single for say diffuse map on this particular issue.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1n0rDFoNlvtjlWzuslymM4MG37alDH1Wt?usp=drive_link here's the attachmen
Added image attachments

notice that the uvmap name is joined and there are corresponding texture for parts that can be selected by press l hover

here we can see the uv map also have the same naming with its texture and uv islands
PROBLEM:

just like the tuts i arrange the uv island by selecting bake uv map and the arranging but what it did also change how the texture is presented on my model

Thank you for your help!

You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page, instead of asking users to visit links just to understand your question. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.sstatic.net/vHwEx.png) and use the tools on the site to upload images directly. See: How to upload an image to a post?.

You need to add a UVMap node to you shader which lets you select which map to use. Add that one on your "Bake To" object with the Joined uv set selected, plug that into the texture you're baking to.
